# iOS Framework Error: Invalid Bundle Structure - binary file is not permitted

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I have a dynamic framework (framework A) that embeds a third party static framework (frameworkB) but throws the below error on app store review:

`Invalid bundle structure. The "Sample.app/Frameworks/frameworkA.framework/Frameworks/frameworkB.a" binary file is not permitted. Your app cannot contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/placing_content_in_a_bundle (ID: d6de5d67-83a8-467a-8c88-7a87b5a2819d)`

Others on stackoverflow say to make sure the executable isn't in **Copy Bundle Resources** which I've already checked. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`frameworkB.a` is not a framework but a static library - this is the problem, because you put it into `Frameworks` folder.

iOS expects only dynamic frameworks inside of a Framework folder. Dynamic framework is a folder with `.framework` extension, which contains dynamic library binary inside.

If you wanted to use `frameworkB` as a static framework or library in your project, it should be linked with `frameworkA` and with that, embedded into the `frameworkA` target's binary, it should not be shipped as standalone static framework / library.

The best workaround would be to link the content of `frameworkB.a` into a dynamic binary of `frameworkA`.

Check if "Embed" is set to "Do Not Embed" for `frameworkB.a` in "Frameworks and libraries" section in General settings of `frameworkA` target or if `frameworkB` is absent in "Embed Frameworks" build phase of `frameworkA` target.

Comment: Thanks for your info, Eugene! We do have frameworkB set to Embed without signing and I do see that frameworkB is included in the Link Binary with Libraries build phase of frameworkA. Does that sound correct to you?

Comment: @Thanh33 That's exactly the problem. Set it to "Do Not Embed".

Comment: I see... we found that we had to embed it to avoid "no such module" errors being thrown for frameworkB when the client application attempted to build

Comment: @Thanh33 That problem should be solved differently - you should specify correct "Library search paths" and "Framework search paths" in Build Settings of frameworkA. Try adding "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR" to search paths.